# How to change `$(UserRootDir)` macro on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting linking errors in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. Specifically this:

[image]

So I investigated. I looked at my project properties and inherited property sheets and I can't find this on `Project Properties->Linker->Input` So I looked at the default property sheets and I found the Microsoft has default property sheets. This investigation led me to what noticing that the `$(UserRootDir)` macro is wrong. The current `$(UserRootDir)` value is this:

[image]

I need the `$(UserRootDir)` to point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0` instead. How do I change that?

Comment: It is not a linker error and has nothing to do with $(UserRootDir).  You need to obtain an ancient version of the DirectX SDK, at least a decade old.  Follow the project's build instructions first.  Googling "qedit.h dxtrans.h" might help.

Comment: This error occurred form migrating a vs2013 project into vs2017. Do you have any recommendations on how to do this carefully? I'm aware I have to update the libs that the project depends on. But I'm not quite sure how to make the appropriate updates.